# Pandas World Cup 2018 dataset goal difference

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a World Cup 2018 dataset from kaggle. [World Cup Fifa statistics](https://www.kaggle.com/mathan/fifa-2018-match-statistics#FIFA%202018%20Statistics.csv)

In this dataset, each row represents not the match, but the team and its scores in the game.

For example:

[image: World Cup, fifa-2018-match-statistics]

How can I calculate the goal difference of each team from this dataset. I mean are there any easier way or **pandas trick** .

My calculation is this:

```
goal_diff = {}
teams = df["Team"].unique()
for t in teams:
    goal_diff[t] = df[df["Team"] == t]["Goal Scored"].sum() \
                 - df[df["Opponent"] == t]["Goal Scored"].sum()
```

Thanks for your replies.

Answer (score 3):

You can aggregate by [`GroupBy.sum`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.sum.html), subtract and last convert to `dict`:

```
goal_diff = ((df.groupby('Team')["Goal Scored"].sum() - 
              df.groupby('Opponent')["Goal Scored"].sum()).to_dict())
print (goal_diff)

{'Argentina': -3, 'Australia': -3, 'Belgium': 10, 
 'Brazil': 5, 'Colombia': 3, 'Costa Rica': -3, 
 'Croatia': 5, 'Denmark': 1, 'Egypt': -4, 
 'England': 4, 'France': 8, 'Germany': -2, 
 'Iceland': -3, 'Iran': 0, 'Japan': -1, 
 'Korea Republic': 0, 'Mexico': -3, 'Morocco': -2,
 'Nigeria': -1, 'Panama': -9, 'Peru': 0,
 'Poland': -3, 'Portugal': 0, 'Russia': 4, 
 'Saudi Arabia': -5, 'Senegal': 0, 'Serbia': -2, 
 'Spain': 1, 'Sweden': 2, 'Switzerland': 0, 
 'Tunisia': -3, 'Uruguay': 4}
```

Answer (score 0):

if you sum goal scored grouping by Team, you get the number of goal scored by that team. if you sum goal scored grouping by Opponent, you get the number of goal received by that team. total goal difference is the difference between them.

```
df.groupby("Team").sum()["Goal Scored"] - df.groupby("Opponent").sum()["Goal Scored"]
```

Comment: what does this add that isn't present in the existing answer?

Comment: nothing. I was writing and didn't realize that a new comment was posted